# Can I change the colour of the terminal tab based on the title?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I accidentally ran a command on the wrong computer because I didn't notice I was SSHed into my Pi:

[image]

Thankfully nothing went wrong, but I would like it if I could change the colours of the terminal (e.g. the background or the tab colour) based on the title of the terminal (in this case either `pi@Kite` or `tim@Hairy17`).

I'm thinking of something like this:

[image]

Comment: Probably easier to change the terminal background than the tab title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gnome-terminal` does not let you change the tab color, and does not provide any automatic means of changing the background color based on the title. It provides an explicit means of changing the background color, e.g.:

```
echo -ne '\e]11;#abcdef\a'
```

If you like this, I recommend to hook it up to your shell prompt on all the hosts you use (including the local one) (e.g. `PS1=$'...\[\e]11;#abcdef\a\]...'`, with varying colors of course) so that it's reverted when you exit ssh.

Note that this approach changes the background color for all the history of the terminal (similarly to changing the background color in the profile settings), rather than just for the output produced on the given host.

By the way, simply having a different shell prompt (maybe consisting of different colors) could already help a lot.

Comment: I simply added the echo line into my .bashrc. Is that right?

Comment: Then it's not going to be reverted when you log out from the remote host.